# Windows 8 Modern UI Styles for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I want my WPF app to look like WinRT apps:

[image]

Are there any ready-made styles or controls available for WPF that lets us achieve this?

Comment: Try Windows Blend. http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx

Comment: Minimalism does not equal 'no design', that's a big misconception. If anything, minimalism requires that you think about design MORE, not less. For instance using icons without text requires that their meaning is crystal clear, using only 2 or 3 large areas in your app requires that you rethink how the information is structured, and rethink what information is absolutely necessary and desirable to the user etc etc

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take a look at [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)

Apps like [Github for Windows use / are based on it.](https://github.com/blog/1151-designing-github-for-windows)

Answer (score 23):

Another nice library for Metroesque-styling of WPF apps is [Modern UI for WPF](http://mui.codeplex.com). Can be installed via NuGet or as a project template.