# Vb.net windows 8 styled program

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, microsoft-metro

I am making Windows 8 style program, and i made some buttons (Class). I would like to create an rectangle box(Visual basic powerpack etc..) and to move the buttons only inside of it, and when it's being dragged to between the buttons, the others will let him between them.

I hope i wasn't too confusing, and i'm kinda new to VB.net.
Here's the preview of it:[image]

Comment: do you have a question?  if it is `how do I do this` this is the wrong site.

Comment: Can you give me the Right site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893909/windows-8-modern-ui-styles-for-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) library which is oriented to MetroApps developing (on WinForms) and contains a lot of usercontrols to do all what you need, for example the `MetroTileItem` control that you can see in the next image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use WPF for this. But if you'll be using WinForms then I suggest Telerik's Panorama. Here's the link to it :)

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/panorama-overview.html

[image]